# Image won't crop in WordPress 3.2.1

Tags: php, wordpress, image-manipulation, wordpress-theming

For some reason my post thumbnails won't crop. They will resize but the same aspect ratio is kept. This results in only one dimension being correct. Here is the code in my functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) ); // Add support for posts
set_post_thumbnail_size( 193, 225, true );
```

I also tried changing the default crop value, in my media.php file, to "true" but it still wouldn't work. Any suggestion would be wonderful.

Also, I am on a shared hosting server from bluehost but I am almost positive php-gd or another image manipulation library is installed on it.

Thanks

EDIT: The site I am working on is lbk.newcoastmedia.com. The post thumbnails I am trying to get to work on the thumbnails in the third box from the top. Under the heading of "Life in the LBK".

Comment: That's weird.  I have lots of sites on bluehost and they all work.  Did you upload the images before adding `set_post_thumbnail_size` to your code? I think the cropping and sizing happens on upload, not when you output the image HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same issue with 2 Wordpress sites I developed. The only way I found to override the skewed images was to assign a class all my thumbnail img tags and set the dimensions manually in the css and add !important. Although this worked for me I pretty sure there has to be some way to programatically set the dimensions in the PHP. Solutions would be appreciated; I believe my company's launching a new division soon and they're most likely going to want a Wordpress blog for it and I'm not particularly fond of adding classes to every thumbnail on my site.